# Programmatic vs Administrative configuration

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms

In JavaEE, JMS has **Administered Objects** and it has a following definition:

> Administered objects that are **configured administratively**, **as opposed to programmatically**.The message provider allows these objects to be configured, and makes them available in the JNDI namespace. They are created only once and they are of two types: *Connection factories* and *Destinations*.

I googled for two definitions, but for it still remains unclear what is the difference. 
[My reference](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-wcf-services/0596526997/ch01s10.html)

Answer (score 0):

- Configured administratively  mean somebody who has administrative privileges can do configuration settings using tools provided by application or by directly editing configuration files of application.
- Configured programmatically means whatever configuration application requires can be done programmatically using APIs provided by application.

End result of both approaches is same i.e. configuring application.

Comment: If I write a POJO that deals with JMS and creates adiministative objects where are those privileges declared or setting perfomed?

Answer (score 0):

The two techniques shown so far for configuring both the client and service complement each other. Administrative configuration gives you the option to change major aspects of the service and the client post-deployment, without even the need to rebuild or redeploy. The major downside of administrative configuration is that it is not type-safe, and configuration errors will only be discovered at runtime.

Programmatic configuration is useful when the configuration decision is either completely dynamicwhen it is taken at runtime based on the current input or conditionsor when the decision is static and never changes, in which case you might as well hardcode it. For example, if you are interested in hosting in-proc calls only, you might as well hardcode the use of the NetNamedPipeBinding and its configuration. However, by and large, most clients and services do resort to using a config file.

Comment: I have stated this as "My Reference"